# Data is being displayed from cache memory

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made a web application using PHP and JavaScript, in which I am displaying data in jQuery data table using PHP in the following way:

```
<tbody>
  <?php
  $query= "SELECT * FROM `tblsiccode` WHERE status='1'";
  $found=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  $i=1;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($found)){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo($i);?></td>
      <td><?php echo($row['SicID']);?></td>
      <td><?php echo($row['SicNumber']);?></td>
      <td><?php echo($row['Description']);?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
  }
  ?>
</tbody>
```

Now I made an `edit.php`, there I am updating details and then redirecting it to data table page (i.e. `sic-details.php`).

The problem is after the updating is successful, when I redirect to `sic-details.php`, the data is still the old one. When I clear the cache, then reload it, then the updated data is shown.

How can I prevent old data from showing after updating the values? For redirect I am using `window.location`.

Comment: Use cache busting for instance somefile.php?123423124 (random number) or send proper Cache-control (or Expires) header from server side

Comment: @ibowankenobi can you please post some links...

Comment: cache control https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control and for cache busting https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Comment: Append current date timestamp each time you hit the page.This will tell the browser that the url is new and don't load from cache.something like this `something.php?dt=new Date().getTime();  `

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for replying, i resolved my problem by adding following lines at the top of my .php files

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")."GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

and it worked.